# PHP "duzun/hQuery.php" POST request

Tags: php, post

Found nice **scraper** developed by **duzun** and I want to make use of it, but I facing one issue.
How can I make POST request. I have tried code as below, but It is not working as expected (at least by Me). Issue is that POST data is not `send/accepted`. Response is same as without POST call (usual simple request).

I didn't find much information regarding this issue. Please help me do so.

```
use duzun\hQuery;

hQuery::$cache_path = "/tmp/cache";

$data = ['topt[1][min]' => '3'];
        
$headers = [
    'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept' => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'
];
$doc = hQuery::fromUrl('SOME HOME PAGE', $headers, $data);
```

Comment: You don't need to write code starts and code ends.

Answer (score 1):

I see no issue with your code. 
Maybe the receiving server doesn't understand the request?
By default this query would have 'content-type' == 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', but destination server might be expecting different format.

An alternative is to use `stream_context_create()` to create a `$context`, then call `hQuery::fromFile($url, false, $context)`.

Here is an example:

```
$data = ['topt' => [1 => ['min' => '3']]];
$url = 'SOME HOME PAGE';

$postdata = http_build_query($data);

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n".
                     "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36\r\n".
                     "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$doc = hQuery::fromFile($url, false, $context)

// or
// $html = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
// $doc = hQuery::fromHTML($html, $url)
```

You can make the POST any way you like, and let `hQuery` handle the parsing of HTML.